# Group By error 33 : wrong number of parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am kind of new to Spark and programming too and i am not able to understand how to deal with Rdd of type `rdd.RDD[(Int, Iterable[Double])] = ShuffledRDD[10] at groupByKey` . I am little bit interested in learning groupByKey in spark and i have a filtered RDD

`scala> p.first
res11: (Int, Double) = (1,299.98)`

I go the above result after applying GroupByKEy instead of reduceByKey now i have rdd of type (Int, Iterable[Double]) and i want to get result like (Int , sum (Double)).
I  have tried this but got the error.

```
    scala> val price = g.map((a,b) => (a, sum(b)))
<console>:33: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
         val price = g.map((a,b) => (a, sum(b)))
```

Please suggest and help me in this to understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`g.mapValues(_.sum)`, which is short for `g.map { case (k, v) => (k, v.sum) }`

Comment: Thank you @Tzach Zohar for this explanation , it helped me a lot , i have a silly question please bare with me ,  what is the importance of case in map .

Comment: `case` is part of a pattern matching expression, the expression above is shorthand for `g.map(r => r match { case (k, v) => (k, v.sum) })`. You can learn about pattern matching here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html and about this shorter syntax here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html

Comment: Note: `mapValues` is _not_ short for corresponding `map`, it will calculate the new value on every access while `map` calculates it once for all values.